# imagining the scale of a type 3 civilzation

Tags: science-in-society

I was browsing worldbuilding when i came across this post
[War between two type III civilizations from the perspective of a type II civilization](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/50667/war-between-two-type-iii-civilizations-from-the-perspective-of-a-type-ii-civiliz)

I was amazed at the sheer power of a type 3 civilization compared to even a type 2 and read about the unimaginable things that would take place if a type 3 civilization would even get ***slightly*** close to a type 2 such as:

- lightyear long ships
- technology beyond anything we can produce being like disposable cameras to them
- more people than have ever existed on their planet flowing through their solar system

I am writing about a type 2 civilization that has come in contact with a type 3 and was hoping that I could get some insight into what sort of unimaginable things that a type 2 civilization would see if  a type 3 civilization started moving through their galaxy/solar system

assumptions:

-lets assume they have a shape similar to ours thus needing actual ships which could accommodate them

Comment: Why exactly would they have impractical ships that take a year for light to pass by?

Comment: in the link, one of the comments involved that statement, I was just restating it to explain what I meant by unimaginable things

Comment: This question is very broad, as well as opinion based. Who knows what drives this alien species? What their motivations, desires, or goals might be? What their physiology is like? All those things will play a role in what they might build. You really need to constrain your question, otherwise we could be listing impossible, or improbable things all day long and only scratch the surface of things which a Level 3 civilization might build/accomplish.

Comment: Don't the linked question/answers indicate that humans on Earth, being where they are today on the Kardashev scale, cannot imagine/comprehend the capabilities of a KIII civilization, making this question a moot point from the outset?

Comment: Welcome to the site, I agree with @AndreiROM, this is far too broad and opinion based to an extent.  What is unimaginable...we couldn't by definition imagine and the list of things that could potentially amaze us is unlimited.  There is no objective way to compare and two answers to this question.  If you have questions on writing good questions and answers check out the [help] and feel free to visit [chat]

Comment: The only thing we can be sure is how much energy they can harness. If my calculation and sources are right, a type 3 can harness about 100 billions times more energy than a type 2 civ. It's so big that it's hard to conceive what they would do with all that energy.

Comment: I think your assumption probably not valid. A Type III civilization is probably inconceivable. Well plenty of sci-fi writers and crappy Johnny Depp movies have conceived of transcending a human body and placing your consciousness into a machine/computer. So assuming they still have bodies is probably a bad assumption. Its just as likely that they don't.

Comment: I'm amused that the question states that the situation is "unimaginable" and then asks us to imagine it!

Comment: Closest technological comparison of the scale would be an abacus to a pocket supercomputer capable of simulating entire galaxies. Though, this is based on computations rather than energy, so the difference would most likely be even more dramatic between K2 and K3 civs.

Comment: In their explorations, they encountered life in many forms, and watched the workings of evolution on a thousand worlds. They saw how often the first faint sparks of intelligence flickered and died in the cosmic night. 

And because, in all the Galaxy, they had found nothing more precious than Mind, they encouraged its dawning everywhere. They became farmers in the fields of stars; they sowed, and sometimes they reaped. 

And sometimes, dispassionately, they had to weed.  Arthur C Clarke

Answer (score 3):

The Kardachev scale actually doesn't say anything about technology.  It is purely focused on energy usage.  We in our culture typically assume these go hand in hand, because currently our technology is the most effective way to consume large quantities of energy, but that's merely an assumption based on our own culture.  It's up to you to decide how your civilization will look in your work.

If we make a few reasonable assumptions, we can pare down some of the options a bit.  The first reasonable assumption is that the civilization's approach to time is extremely long-sighted.  It's really hard to become a Class III civilization quickly, so they likely have a great history to draw from.  (Alternate: they may have royally screwed up, and their Class III civilization may be living on borrowed time).  They would most likely be very aware of the lifespan of stars, and their civilization would flex around their eventual demise (when was the last time you planned for the eventual death of our Sun?)

Another key thing to look at is how much they pay attention to energy.  A civilization like that would consume a *massive* amount of energy.  Current estimates are that there are roughly 100 billion galaxies.  They consume 0.00001% of the total energy in our known universe. You, as an author, now need to decide whether there are other energy sources out there which are not known to terrestrial physicists today.  If there are not, then they should be *very* aware of their energy usage, and be as efficient as they possibly can.  If you decide that your civilization is aware of some yet undiscovered energy source, they may be less frugal if you wish.

The final thing to consider is dynamic range.  The civilization clearly needs to be aware of energy on the order of 10^59J range, because that's the amount of energy believed to be in our galaxy.  How aware are they of energy on the scale of 10^22J, where our energy levels are as a planet?  If their awareness does not reach across this dynamic range, then they wouldn't even stop to give us the time of day.  We would literally not register to them, as a planet!

One interesting solution, especially from the perspective of trying to write stories about such civilizations, is to have a distributed civilization.  Instead of everything being decided at the galactic level (the equivalent of every important decision going through congress), they may distribute their society.  There may be parts which are responsible for managing small areas, with small amounts of energy (like planetary sized amounts of energy).  They would be given direction from the upper galactic decision makers, but they would have some level of autonomy to try to be as efficient as possible with the resources provided.

Such a distributed culture has a few advantages.  The first is that it lets us interact with an entity whose energy budget is imaginable.  It might be like meeting the pinky toenail of the Class III civilization, but you can at least imagine it.  The next advantage is that it gives the opportunity for the civilization to be more efficient by adapting their processes to the environment rather than trying to adapt the environment to their processes.  Finally, structures like this are similar to those we have on Earth, just on a much more grandiose scale.  This means that you can draw on prior art from our world, making it easier for the reader to relate.

Comment: Interesting point on the energy consumption of a K3 relative to the known universe. Anyone want to do the calculation for how much they'd accelerate the impending heat death of the universe?